# Создание интерактивной карты

Tags: javascript, c#

Как можно сделать интерактивную карту ?

Есть большой JPG - карта
Хотелось бы ставить на нём различные точки при наведение на которые давалась бы заранее заготовленная информация - ну и таймеры бы не помешала.

Возможно есть какой то ресурс где можно сделать.

Но так же могу осилить и на JS / С#

Кто то знает куда копать.

Comment: в svg попробуйте карту перевести

Comment: если это настоящая карта, можно взять какие-то границы из osm, можно больше было бы сказать глядя на картинку

Comment: Если настоящая карта то можно ещё обратиться к OpenStreetMaps, у них есть api для всех таких вещей (добавление маркеров на карту с описаниями итд). Она легко встраивается средствами js